# Creating an attachment in SharePoint from Microsoft Forms Response - Get File Content using path not working

Tags: forms, sharepoint, power-automate

I am trying to add contents and an attachment from a Form to a SharePoint list. However, the Get file content using path action in my flow is failing. The error I'm receiving says "Unauthorized" and in the file content box, I receive the following message:

"status": 401,
"message": "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).",
"source": "apidod.connectorp.svc.ms"

The file path is as follows (minus the front of the path):

sites/HSMWINGATLANTIC_Supply_Requests/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?newTargetListUrl=%2Fsites%2FHSMWINGATLANTIC%5FSupply%5FRequests%2FShared%20Documents&viewpath=%2Fsites%2FHSMWINGATLANTIC%5FSupply%5FRequests%2FShared%20Documents%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&id=%2Fsites%2FHSMWINGATLANTIC%5FSupply%5FRequests%2FShared%20Documents%2FApps%2FMicrosoft%20Forms%20Fairfax%2FVehicle%20Rental%20Request%2FSupporting%20Documents&viewid=55590b8b%2D4994%2D4e8b%2D804b%2D24f4774c21e920220815 - HSM-40 Truck Request for 15 AUG 20_Charles Power 1.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the issue. This wasn’t working because it is a group form and form responses are sent to the group’s SharePoint site; not the user’s OneDrive. Therefore, the Get file content action should be using the SharePoint connector instead of OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

c.d.power

For that Get File content using path you would need a relative path without the site url part. You can actually extract the correct path with an expression.

In the example below I retrieve the link property from the Attachment question answer value. I use a [json](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#json) function to turn it into an array, since Microsoft returns a string value for some reason ;)

After that I use [nthindexof](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#nthindexof) to determine at which forward slash (starting position of string) I need to slice with a [slice](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#slice) function, in this case the 7th instance, which is index 6.

This should retrieve the part which we need for a get file content using path action. With a [decodeUriComponent](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#decodeUriComponent) function I make sure the %20 is turned back into space characters.

*Make sure you update the question id to your question id.*

```
decodeUriComponent(slice(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/re67e0cfcd95d488593347d93f2728204'])[0]['link'], nthindexof(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/re67e0cfcd95d488593347d93f2728204'])[0]['link'], '/', 6)))
```

[image]

Comment: Expiscornovus, thank you for the reply. I tried the code and it was accepted as valid; however, when I run the test, it fails and gives me this error: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Get_file_content_using_path' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'json' expects its parameter to be a string or an XML. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#json for usage details.'.  To be clear, I am not entirely sure what the question id should be.

Comment: Just to double check. Did you change/update my question id (re67e0cfcd95d488593347d93f2728204) to your question id?